# binding linq query result to gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I am finding it difficult to bind the linq query results to a gridview control on my asp.net page.  In the main Linq Query, i am getting all the users from one table which meets the criteria of a column that checks for "Form Completed" -

```
using (COLA_AccreditationEntities4 eFactory = new COLA_AccreditationEntities4())
{
    var evaluations = eFactory.Symposium_Evaluation.Where(a => 
            (!a.Completed.HasValue || 
              a.Completed.Value == 0) && a.Active && a.UserID >= 2063).ToList();
```

Then inside the code i am doing a foreach loop to get all the userid from the other table that matches the userid in the previous table -

```
foreach (var eval in evaluations)
{
    var user = eFactory.SYMPOSIUM_Users.Where(a => a.UserID == eval.UserID.Value 
                         && a.Active.Value && a.UserRole == 1).FirstOrDefault();

    if (user != null && !users.Contains(user.UserID))
    {
        string name = user.FirstName + " " + user.LastName;
        string email = user.Email;
    }
}
```

All i wanted to do is to show the user.firstname + user.lastname + user.email on the screen.  I used gridview control to bind this, but not getting desired results.

Any thoughts on how to achieve this ?

Comment: when binding the gridview to the query results, i am getting "Data source is an invalid type.  It must be either an IListSource, IEnumerable, or IDataSource."  error - i tried couple of resolutions in this forum by using .ToList(), but i am not getting the intellisense for .ToList().  GridView1.DataSource = user.ToList();
                        GridView1.DataBind();

Comment: Can you show how you bind the GridView? Please show the complete Page_Load eventhandler.

Comment: @MalcolmFrexner Frexner i put the above method inside a click event which is not in the Page_Load method.

Comment: What is the return type of the following query: eFactory.SYMPOSIUM_Users.Where(a => a.UserID == eval.UserID.Value && a.Active.Value && a.UserRole == 1) if I'm right it should be an IEnumerable of your type. If that's true you should be able to Bind it by just assigning it to the DataSource of the grid.

Answer (score 2):

you should be able to bind to your grid straight from your query:

`var users = eFactory.SYMPOSIUM_Users.Where(a => a.UserID == eval.UserID.Value && a.Active.Value && a.UserRole == 1);
this.mygrid.DataSource = users;

I would suggest taking a look at the [asp.net](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/data-access) web site for tutorials. Lots of good content out there.

**Update:**
Perhaps your best solution is to create an anonymous type from a join on your two tables, this way your not repeatedly querying your data store, and your databinding will be simpler.

```
var result = (from i in eFactory.Symposium_Evaluation
              join user in eFactory.SYMPOSIUM_Users on i.UserID equals user.UserID
              where user.UserRole == 1 &&
                   ((!i.Completed.HasValue || 
                     i.Completed.Value == 0) && 
                    i.Active && a.UserID >= 2063)
              select new {
                  User = user,
                  Symposium = i
              }).ToList();

myDataGrid.DataSource = result;
myDataGrid.DataBind();
```

Now in your grid row template you can:

```
<%#Eval("User.FirstName")%>
<%#Eval("User.LastName")%>
<%#Eval("User.Email")%>
```

Comment: thanks, but i have tried the method you have suggested, already, (in my comment section) and i am getting an error as listed above.

Answer (score 0):

Define a List of user type

```
List<User> users= new List<User>();
```

Modify your second code block like below

```
foreach (var eval in evaluations)
{
    var user = eFactory.SYMPOSIUM_Users.Where(a => a.UserID == eval.UserID.Value 
                         && a.Active.Value && a.UserRole == 1).FirstOrDefault();

    if (user != null && !users.Contains(user.UserID))
    {
        users.Add(user);  
    }
}
```

Modify your binding code inside gridview as

```
<%#Eval("FirstName")%>
<%#Eval("LastName")%>
```

And finally bind your grid with the list of users

```
this.mygrid.DataSource = users;
this.mygrid.DataBind();
```