# binding join query result to Gridview in c#

Tags: c#, linq, gridview, join, bind

i am trying to bind the result of two joined tables into my gridview using linq or entityframework 
I have

```
EmployeeData_Main Table (MainID, FirstName , SecondName ,LastName , DateOfBirth)
EmployeeData_Sub Table (SubID ,Address,Email,Tele,MainID-FK-)
```

I am using this query to bind:

```
var queryResult = (from maindata 
    in db.EmployeeData_Main 
    join subData in db.EmployeeData_Sub 
        on maindata.MainID equals subData.MainID 
    select new 
    { 
        EmployeeData_Main = maindata, 
        EmployeeData_Sub = subData 
    })
    .ToList();

GV.DataSource = queryResult;
GV.DataBind();
```

I bind fields using `EmployeeData_Main.FirstName` etc,but came out with this exception:

```
DataBinding: '<>f__AnonymousType0`2[[HR.EmployeeData_Main, HR, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null],
[HR.EmployeeData_Sub, HR, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]' does not contain a property with the name 'MainID'.
```

i read some topics like 
[How can I bind a query with a join to a GridView, with a Linq datasource with a business layer and data access layer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15150363/how-can-i-bind-a-query-with-a-join-to-a-gridview-with-a-linq-datasource-with-a)
&
[binding linq query result to gridview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13018978/binding-linq-query-result-to-gridview)

However i still getting the same exception. how to bind the result successfully

Comment: I tried to project result with :
` select new 
                    { 
                        FN = maindata.FirstName , 
                        SN = maindata.SecondName ,
                        LN = maindata.LastName , 
                        DOB = maindata.DateofBirth,
                        SubID = subData.SubID ,
                        Address = subData.Address,
                        Email = subData.Email,
                        Tele = subData.Tele
                    }).ToList(); '

& bind using "FN" "SN" etc ,but didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your list is a list of anonymous type with only **two** properties : `EmployeeData_Main` and `EmployeeData_Sub`.

Then, the property you want to bind is `EmployeeData_Main.MainID`, which is not directly part of the anonymous type. So your binding can't work.

I don't know if you are using the `GridView` from WebForms or WPF, but in WPF, you can bind it this way :

```
{ EmployeeData_Main.MainID }
```

Or you can select your property in your anonymous type :

```
var queryResult = (from maindata in db.EmployeeData_Main 
                   join subData in db.EmployeeData_Sub 
                       on maindata.MainID equals subData.MainID 
   select new { MainID = maindata.MainID, EmployeeData_Main = maindata, EmployeeData_Sub = subData })
   .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the grid is trying to find the property `queryResult.MainID` while it should be looking for `queryResult.EmployeeData_Main.MainID`. I do not know if that is actually possible.

You could specifically declare which fields to select like:

```
var queryResult = (from maindata in db.EmployeeData_Main 
    join subData in db.EmployeeData_Sub on maindata.MainID equals subData.MainID 
    select new { 
        maindata.MainID, 
        maindata.FirstName , 
        maindata.SecondName ,
        maindata.LastName , 
        maindata.DateOfBirth,
        subData.SubID ,
        subData.Address,
        subData.Email,
        subData.Tele,
        subData.MainID-FK-
    }).ToList();
```